# Why doesn't my register contain the value I calculate from the asm

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm in a gdb session for a post-mortem analysis of a crash and am analyzing this assembly code of a function, starting from the beginning of the function:

```
   0x0000000001b0af00 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000001b0af01 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000001b0af04 <+4>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000001b0af05 <+5>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x0000000001b0af08 <+8>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000001b0af0c <+12>:    mov    0x18(%rdi),%rdi
=> 0x0000000001b0af10 <+16>:    mov    (%rdi),%rdx
```

The crash happens for a null dereference of rdi:

```
(gdb) info registers rdi
rdi            0x0      0
```

Fine. But reading that assembly (which is pretty straight-forward), I don't see how the rdi value came to be null. Notice that rbx, which has the original value of rdi from the +5 instruction offset, has this:

```
(gdb) info registers rbx
rbx            0x7f4fb26b9690   139980272539280
```

From there, rdi should have the dereferenced value of that address plus 0x18 (due to instruction offset +12):

```
(gdb) x/a (0x7f4fb26b9690 + 0x18)
0x7f4fb26b96a8: 0x7f4f74632bb0
```

Note that's not zero. The value at rdi, as I see it, should be `0x7f4f74632bb0`. What am I misunderstanding?

This is x64 assembly generated from GCC 4.8 compiling C++ code.

Comment: Please include an example of how the function is called.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews why is that relevant? I would instead investigate where that address is (looks like some shared lib?) and whether it's correctly in the core file (I assume this post mortem is from a core file?).

Comment: A wild & unlikely theory would be that some shared state amongst multiple threads resides at address 0x7f4fb26b96a8; that it was zero at the time `mov 0x18(%rdi),%rdi;` executed, but was overwritten with a non-zero value between that read and the dereference.

Comment: FYI you can use `$rbx` in GDB expressions like `x /a ($rbx + 0x18)

Comment: Yes, you're understanding the asm correctly.  Either your core file isn't an accurate snapshot of mem+regs, or some kind of asynchronous modification to memory happened between the first and 2nd load (like fifoforlifo suggested).  I guess `0x7f4f74632bb0` is also a valid pointer so the load + deref should have worked.  Is your program multi-threaded, or does it have any signal handlers installed?

Comment: Does the rest of the function have any jump instructions into that section of code?

Comment: Best guess -- this is the top of a loop, so there's a backwards branch to +12 or +16 later in the code, and the null is hit on a later iteration.  It looks like it might be traversing down a linked list without checking for the null at the end?  Since `rdi` is the first argument (usually `this` in a method), this might be a recursive call that has been tail-call optimized into a loop?

Comment: Could you post more of the disassembly to see if Chris's simple suggestion with the loop fits?

Comment: @Jester (and Chris Dodd): Thanks for the suggestions. Jumping back is a good idea to consider. However there are no jumps back into this code from later in this function. I think out of respect for my employer I better not post more code than this since this is a proprietary function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're understanding the asm correctly.  Either your core file isn't an accurate snapshot of mem+regs, or some kind of asynchronous modification to memory happened between the first and 2nd load (like fifoforlifo suggested).

I guess `0x7f4f74632bb0` is also a valid pointer so the load + deref should have worked if the value had been present sooner.

Is your program multi-threaded, or does it have any signal handlers installed?

A plausible scenario:

- A function passed the address of a local to another thread
- Then it returned while the other thread still had the pointer.  So now it points to unused space below RSP.
- Another function is then called, and one of its locals happens to be in the location that other threads were still modifying.

---

(Or some other explanation I haven't thought of.)

**update: if a branch jumps backward into this, like @ChrisDodd suggested, this could be part of a linked-list traversal loop.**

That's also very plausible.  `objdump` doesn't mark branch targets in its disassembly ([Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler](https://agner.org/optimize/) does), so leaving out the rest of the function may have been highly misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is multithreaded. Can that be the cause of this behavior? We're looking at stack variables, though: how could another thread write them. rdi is a this pointer of a polmorphic type.

Comment: @firebush: if some previous function gave out a pointer to a local and then returned while another thread was still using it, that could explain this situation.

Comment: Thanks Peter. (Thanks too for the $rbx syntax, btw.) As mentioned in reply to Chris Dodd, there is no jump back into this part of the code. There's only a single jump and it jumps forward, not back. I do suspect you're right that there's an issue with multithreading where another thread overwrote the value in this address.